# VirtualBox and Wireless interface Bridging?

Tags: wireless-networking, virtualbox, bridging

Can anyone please tell me how does **VirtualBox 4.1.4 OSE** version bridges the connection with the wireless Interface (**wlan0**). Yes! It was working fine in my guest :) . I read the Documentation at their site but that was not in depth.

And there are no extra interface in your host system when you do the bridging like the one which we make while using **Bridge-Utils** in **KVM** or like the one which **VMWare** make called **VMnet0**.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Many virtual machine programs come with a special **"bridge" or "filter" driver** which attaches to existing network interfaces and allows the program to send and receive packets (Ethernet frames) directly. For VirtualBox on Linux, this is done by `vboxnetflt` kernel module when you choose *"Bridged networking"* in VBox settings. With this mode, the guest will be in the same IP network as the host.

Another equally common function is **NAT** – this works at a higher level and without any drivers. Whenever the guest attempts to start a TCP handshake, VirtualBox simply opens a TCP connection as if it were an ordinary program. (Similar for UDP and to a certain level ICMP.) VirtualBox even responds to the guest's DHCP requests.

---

VirtualBox *does* have its own virtual network interfaces like VMWare – they can be created in "Host-only networking" mode, and are usually named `vbox*`. This again needs a kernel driver, `vboxnetadp` on Linux.

Comment: thanks for the reply, it was really helpful. Is there any documentation which can give me more details or any references for your above post? And does that driver `vboxnetflt` works for any interface (like wlan and pppoe and eth)

Comment: It should work for any Ethernet-like interface (eth, wlan, tap, br...) I haven't tested it with other kinds such as tun or ppp, but it *probably* won't work with those, since they work at a different layer...